# Set dynamically added dropdownlist selected value which is a Variable

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a button which on click add a `dropdownlist dynamically` into a div,
and then i need to set selected value for each added `dropdown`.

Here the **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/satinder_singh1/fpawm/1/)**:

In my demo, there might be `n` number of `containerDiv` and so respective `n` number of  `setSelectedValue_n`
 , I need to set **setSelectedValue_1** for respected **ddl**

**Js:**

```
$("#btn").on('click', function () {
    var setSelectedValue_1 = 'mno';
    var setSelectedValue_2 = 'pqr';
    var setSelectedValue_3 = 'abc';
    $('.containerDiv').each(function () {

        var ddGenerate = '<select><option>abc</option><option>pqr</option>option>xyz</option> <option>mno</option></select>';
        $(this).append(ddGenerate);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fpawm/2/)

added value attribute here in each option

change

```
var ddGenerate = '<select><option value="abc">abc</option><option value="pqr">pqr</option><option value="xyz">xyz</option> <option>mno</option></select>';
                                    ^ //added value attribute here in each option
```

Read [**.appendTo()**](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) and [**.val()**](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
 $(ddGenerate).val('abc').appendTo($(this));
```

full code

```
$("#btn").on('click', function () {
    var setSelectedValue_1 = 'mno';
    var setSelectedValue_2 = 'pqr';
    var setSelectedValue_3 = 'abc';
    $('.containerDiv').each(function () {

        var ddGenerate = '<select><option value="abc">abc</option><option value="pqr">pqr</option><option value="xyz">xyz</option> <option>mno</option></select>';
        $(ddGenerate).val('pqr').appendTo($(this));
    });
});
```

Updated Code

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fpawm/5/)

```
$("#btn").on('click', function () {
    var arr = ['mno', 'pqr', 'abc'];
        $('.containerDiv').each(function (i) {
            var ddGenerate = '<select><option value="abc">abc</option><option value="pqr">pqr</option><option value="xyz">xyz</option> <option>mno</option></select>';
            $(ddGenerate).val(arr[i]).appendTo($(this));
        });
});
```

Comment: +1 for working demo, but this is not working in my actual code, ie the  generated ddl child variable futher append in some container div parent variable which has to selected=true before i append parent div, sorry i know its bit confusing

Comment: ie variable in ddGenerate have to add selected=true as respective place , so this updated variable ddGenerate append into another dynamically generated vairable

Comment: no error is there, i need to update my variable 'ddGenerate' value before appending it

Comment: @Satindersingh are you using exact code as i have written ??I have changed `ddGenerate` also .

Comment: the scenareo is like having 3 variable `variable1` holds ddl html , `variable2` hold div which i recieve from a webservice n variable3 hold other data, then finally i append var1+var2+var3 , i need to update var1 ie ddl html before the final append

Answer (score 1):

do you mean something like this:

```
$("#btn").on('click', function () {
    var arr = ['mno', 'pqr', 'abc'],    
        i = 0;
    $('.containerDiv').each(function () {
        var selected_v = arr[i];
        var ddGenerate = '<select><option value="abc">abc</option><option value="pqr">pqr</option><option value="xyz">xyz</option> <option value="mno">mno</option></select>';
        $(this).append(ddGenerate);
        $(this).find("select option[value='"+selected_v+"']").prop("selected", true);
        i++;
    });
});
```

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fpawm/3/)

Comment: +1 for better code , but this is not working in my actual code, ie the generated ddl child variable futher append in some container div parent variable which has to selected=true before i append parent div, sorry i know its bit confusing

Comment: ie variable in `ddGenerate`  have to add `selected=true` as respective place , so this updated variable `ddGenerate` append into another dynamically generated vairable